# Convert blob to bitmap image in Appcelerator titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have an image's Blob and want to convert it into Bitmap image to use android Canvas, Path and Paint in appcelerator Titanium.
I went through appcelerator docs but couldn't find any method that allows me to convert directly.
I tried converting blob to Base64 string and then create the bitmap object using android native methods through hyperloop but was unsuccessful.

Then I tried converting base64 to byte array and create bitmap using this code by using Hyperloop but bitmap is empty :

```
             var BitmapFactory = require('android.graphics.BitmapFactory');
             var ByteArrayInputStream = require("java.io.ByteArrayInputStream");

            var stringToSaveInDatabase = Ti.Utils.base64encode(newBlob).toString();
            var bytes = [];
            for (var k = 0; k < stringToSaveInDatabase.length; k++) {
                bytes.push(stringToSaveInDatabase.charCodeAt(k));
            }
            var arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(arrayInputStream);
```

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't working correctly since I've used a custom SDK. Converting to a ByteArray works fine like this: `var istream = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(blob.toBase64().toString()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); console.log("istream: " + istream); console.log("bmp: " + BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream));` but the decodeStream returns `null` at the end. That might be the case in your example too. You could save the image first and then use this to load that resource: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24658?focusedCommentId=419466#comment-419466

Comment: yes I am getting null though blob object is present in memory.I found this class https://docs.appcelerator.com/module-apidoc/latest/android/index.html?org/appcelerator/titanium/view/TiDrawableReference.html it has methods :    fromBlob(Activity activity, TiBlob blob)  and getBitmap() which could let me convert from blob to bitmap but I have no idea how to access this class. I tried require("org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiDrawableReference") but I am getting error Requested module not found. Do you have any idea how to access this class and use its methods ?

Comment: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25962?focusedCommentId=437528#comment-437528 accessing core ti classes is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Updated examples:

```
var Activity = require('android.app.Activity')
var ImageView = require('android.widget.ImageView');
var Base64 = require('android.util.Base64');
var BitmapFactory = require('android.graphics.BitmapFactory');
var activity = new Activity(Ti.Android.currentActivity);
var RenderScript = require("android.renderscript.RenderScript");
var Allocation = require("android.renderscript.Allocation");
var Element = require("android.renderscript.Element");
var ScriptIntrinsicBlur = require("android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur");

$.img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    $.img.toImage(function(blob) {
        var encodeByte = Base64.decode(blob.toBase64(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
        var bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);

        const bmpOut = bmp.copy(bmp.getConfig(), true);
        const rs = RenderScript.create(activity);
        const blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        const allIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bmp);
        const allOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bmpOut);

        blurScript.setRadius(2.0);
        blurScript.setInput(allIn);
        blurScript.forEach(allOut);
        allOut.copyTo(bmpOut);
        bmp.recycle();
        rs.destroy();

        var image = new ImageView(activity);
        $.index.add(image);
        image.setImageBitmap(bmpOut);
    })
})

$.index.open();
```

index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ImageView id="img" image="/images/DefaultIcon.png" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

`bmp` will be the Bitmap out of the `ImageView` it will apply a blur and add it to the window again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am getting the following error " Message: Uncaught TypeError: blob.getImage is not a function "

Comment: I've updated the example with working code now! It will clone the ImageView image and add a blured version of it